# MongoDB: how to insert document without repeat

Tags: mongodb, insert

Suppose I already have some data in database:

```
{
   id: 001,
   title: "title_1"
}
{
   id: 002,
   title: "title_2"
}
{
   id: 003,
   title: "title_3"
}
```

then I want to insert some new documents:

```
{
   id: 003    // id repeat
   title: "title_4"
}
{
   id: 004
   title: "title_5"
}
```

but I don't want to insert the `{ id:003 }` item, because some guy in the database already has the same id.

So, how can I let the MongoDB ignore the repeat value(with specified key) item when I insert new data?

Comment: If it is okay to overwrite (but not add a new record) `save` works. Do you not want to overwrite?

Comment: @PaulDraper: Overwrite is Ok

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide your expected final collection results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to create unique index on `id`. You have to try like this:

```
 db.collection.ensureIndex( { id: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a [Unique Index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from putting this as unique index as it was suggested earlier, you can just insert them with a different key. Instead of id key as you already have, you can insert them with unique primary key _id (you can use your own unique _id field if you want so http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#the-id-field)