# MongoDB How to insert batch of documents and ignore duplicates c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to insert batch of documents, some of them already exist in the collection. So what I want is either to ignore them, or a better solution for me would be on the exception I would want to log which document is duplicate, and continue to insert the next documents if possible.

I saw couple of similar questions, but none of them resolved this.

[MongoDB Bulk Insert Ignore Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054651/mongodb-bulk-insert-ignore-duplicate)

[MongoDB: how to insert document without repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701610/mongodb-how-to-insert-document-without-repeat)

I've create my own hash property, because the unique key of my documents will be a multiple keys, so I accumulate them and than calculate the hash for it.

my code look like something like this:

```
        const string connectionString = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/localdb";

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        _database = client.GetDatabase("localdb");

        var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Sales");


StringBuilder customValue;

        foreach (var data in dataCollectionDict)
        {
            customValue = new StringBuilder();

            customValue.Append(data["col1"]);
            customValue.Append(data["col2"]);
            customValue.Append(data["col3"]);
            customValue.Append(data["col4"]);
            customValue.Append(data["col5"]);
            customValue.Append(data["col6"]);

            data.AddRange(new BsonDocument("HashMultipleKey", SHA256Func(customValue.ToString())));
        }


await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(new BsonDocument("HashMultipleKey", 1), new CreateIndexOptions() { Unique = true, Sparse = true ,});


await collection.InsertManyAsync(dataCollectionDict);
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So this is the work around I've found, wasn't sure if that the best solution for this, I'd love to hear if you have a better way for this.

```
      try
        {
            await collection.InsertManyAsync(dataCollectionDict);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationInsights.Instance.TrackException(ex);

            InsertSingleDocuments(dataCollectionDict,collection, dataCollectionQueueMessage);
        }
    }

    private static void InsertSingleDocuments(List<BsonDocument> dataCollectionDict, IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection
        ,DataCollectionQueueMessage dataCollectionQueueMessage)
    {
        ApplicationInsights.Instance.TrackEvent("About to start insert individual docuemnts and to find the duplicate one");

        foreach (var data in dataCollectionDict)
        {
            try
            {
                collection.InsertOne(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ApplicationInsights.Instance.TrackException(ex,new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                    {
                        "Error Message","Duplicate document was detected, therefore ignoring this document and continuing to insert the next docuemnt"
                    }, {
                        "FilePath",dataCollectionQueueMessage.FilePath
                    }}
                );
            }
        }
    }
```